# Referencing a column when extracting inside ifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame ("dat") with sex, age, and raw score as well as two tables ("m", "f"), one for each sex, which contain t-values ordered by raw score (row) and age (column):

```
dat <- data.frame(code = c("A01", "B02"), sex = c("f", "m"), age = c(6, 8), raw.score = c(12, 5))

m <- read.table(textConnection("
36 32 36 33 20 33 32 20 31 33 35 43
38 36 41 40 36 41 36 30 34 40 39 43
42 42 43 42 40 43 38 36 40 44 41 43
42 43 43 46 44 45 41 42 44 45 43 44
43 46 44 47 46 46 44 45 47 49 46 48
44 47 48 47 49 49 45 48 47 50 50 48
45 49 49 48 50 49 45 50 49 51 51 53
47 51 49 50 50 51 46 51 51 55 54 53
51 54 51 51 52 52 49 53 53 57 57 53
54 55 54 52 53 54 51 53 54 60 57 55
55 58 55 55 55 56 52 56 56 60 57 56
55 58 56 55 57 58 53 58 57 61 59 57
56 61 56 56 59 58 54 59 58 61 63 59
57 62 58 57 60 58 55 59 62 62 63 59
58 63 59 58 64 61 58 62 62 63 63 61
60 64 59 60 64 62 59 63 62 63 69 63
62 64 60 61 66 62 59 64 62 63 69 63
62 64 60 62 69 63 61 65 64 63 69 63
62 64 60 64 69 65 62 67 64 65 73 63
62 68 61 65 69 65 62 70 66 67 73 67
62 68 66 65 69 65 63 70 66 70 73 67
62 70 66 65 69 65 64 70 66 70 73 67
64 70 66 67 69 65 65 73 66 70 73 67
64 70 69 73 69 67 66 73 66 70 73 73
64 70 73 73 69 70 66 73 66 73 73 73
68 70 73 73 69 70 68 73 73 73 73 73
68 73 73 73 73 73 70 73 73 73 73 73
73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73
73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73
73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73
73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73
"), header = FALSE)

f <- read.table(textConnection("
32 34 34 34 38 34 34 37 37 20 20 41
32 39 36 34 38 37 38 39 37 32 36 42
41 45 41 47 41 38 40 42 40 40 43 45
44 47 47 47 47 40 44 45 40 46 49 49
47 49 49 50 48 42 46 50 44 48 50 53
48 52 50 50 52 45 48 52 47 48 50 55
51 52 51 51 54 47 49 54 49 51 51 58
53 57 51 53 55 48 50 55 51 53 55 59
54 60 56 54 55 50 50 59 51 56 56 59
55 61 56 56 59 51 51 60 51 56 60 62
56 61 57 58 60 52 54 62 53 60 60 64
59 64 61 58 62 52 56 62 55 60 73 64
59 64 61 59 62 53 58 62 56 62 73 64
59 66 63 59 62 55 59 63 56 62 73 64
62 69 66 60 65 56 59 63 56 62 73 66
62 69 66 60 69 57 59 67 56 62 73 66
62 73 69 62 69 58 60 67 56 64 73 66
62 73 69 62 69 60 60 67 58 64 73 73
62 73 73 63 69 62 60 67 58 64 73 73
62 73 73 66 69 64 63 69 60 64 73 73
62 73 73 69 69 64 66 69 60 64 73 73
64 73 73 69 69 66 68 69 60 68 73 73
64 73 73 69 69 66 68 69 63 68 73 73
64 73 73 69 73 68 70 69 63 68 73 73
68 73 73 69 73 68 70 69 66 68 73 73
73 73 73 69 73 68 70 69 66 68 73 73
73 73 73 73 73 70 73 73 66 68 73 73
73 73 73 73 73 70 73 73 73 68 73 73
73 73 73 73 73 70 73 73 73 73 73 73
73 73 73 73 73 70 73 73 73 73 73 73
73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73
"), header = FALSE)
```

I want to look up the t-values in the tables and add them as a column to the data frame. The correct resulting data frame should look like this:

```
> dat
  code sex age raw.score t.value
1  A01   f   6        12      52
2  B02   m   8         5      45
```

I have tried the following:

```
dat$t.value <- ifelse(
                      dat$sex == "m",
                      m[dat$raw.score, dat$age],
                      f[dat$raw.score, dat$age]
                     )
```

but that does not work. I would have expected the following:

```
> ifelse(
+        dat$sex == "m",
+        m[5, 8],
+        f[12, 6]
+       )
[1] 52 45
```

but `[dat$raw.score, dat$age]` calls the whole columns, instead of only the relevant row:

```
> ifelse(
+        dat$sex == "m",
+        m[dat$raw.score, dat$age],
+        f[dat$raw.score, dat$age]
+       )
[[1]]
[1] 52 42

[[2]]
[1] 58 45
```

**How can I limit the indices in `[dat$raw.score, dat$age]` to only the relevant row of "dat"?**

*My actual code is more complex than the example above. It contains several nested `ifelse()`, so I cannot easily replace that part with another construction.*

---

#### Follow-up Question

I am using @akrun's solution with `mapply()`. In my real data, there are many columns of raw scores ("raw.score.1", "raw.score.2", ...), all of which have to be looked up in many corresponding tables with t-values ("m.1", "f.1", "m.2", "f.2", ...). Therefore, I would like to reuse the function that `mapply()` applies to the data, instead of having to retype it for every variable.

Here is an updated sample code that shows what I would like to do (at the end):

```
# data frame with data
dat <- data.frame(code = c("A01", "B02"), sex = c("f", "m"), age = c(6, 8), raw.score.1 = c(12, 5), raw.score.2 = c(6, 3))

# t-values for first raw score
m.1 <- read.table(textConnection("
36 32 36 33 20 33 32 20 31 33 35 43
38 36 41 40 36 41 36 30 34 40 39 43
42 42 43 42 40 43 38 36 40 44 41 43
42 43 43 46 44 45 41 42 44 45 43 44
43 46 44 47 46 46 44 45 47 49 46 48
44 47 48 47 49 49 45 48 47 50 50 48
45 49 49 48 50 49 45 50 49 51 51 53
47 51 49 50 50 51 46 51 51 55 54 53
51 54 51 51 52 52 49 53 53 57 57 53
54 55 54 52 53 54 51 53 54 60 57 55
55 58 55 55 55 56 52 56 56 60 57 56
55 58 56 55 57 58 53 58 57 61 59 57
"), header = FALSE)

f.1 <- read.table(textConnection("
32 34 34 34 38 34 34 37 37 20 20 41
32 39 36 34 38 37 38 39 37 32 36 42
41 45 41 47 41 38 40 42 40 40 43 45
44 47 47 47 47 40 44 45 40 46 49 49
47 49 49 50 48 42 46 50 44 48 50 53
48 52 50 50 52 45 48 52 47 48 50 55
51 52 51 51 54 47 49 54 49 51 51 58
53 57 51 53 55 48 50 55 51 53 55 59
54 60 56 54 55 50 50 59 51 56 56 59
55 61 56 56 59 51 51 60 51 56 60 62
56 61 57 58 60 52 54 62 53 60 60 64
59 64 61 58 62 52 56 62 55 60 73 64
"), header = FALSE)

# t-values for second raw score
m.2 <- read.table(textConnection("
32 32 34 30 37 40 36 33 38 38 42 44
40 38 36 36 41 44 41 38 42 44 45 47
43 40 40 40 44 48 44 43 46 46 49 51
43 43 42 41 44 50 46 46 49 48 54 52
43 45 42 44 47 52 47 51 49 49 54 53
43 47 44 46 48 54 50 52 50 53 56 55
44 47 46 49 49 55 51 53 52 53 58 55
46 50 48 50 49 56 53 54 55 54 58 55
46 50 49 50 50 57 54 56 56 56 59 55
46 53 51 51 51 57 54 56 56 57 60 55
47 54 51 52 52 58 56 58 58 60 60 56
48 54 54 54 52 59 60 60 60 61 63 57
"), header = FALSE)

f.2 <- read.table(textConnection("
36 36 39 37 42 40 40 41 34 40 43 45
38 36 40 42 46 44 43 46 40 46 47 49
40 40 43 44 48 46 46 51 44 49 47 53
42 46 44 47 50 47 48 52 44 51 50 53
42 46 47 48 52 49 49 54 51 53 52 55
45 49 48 50 57 50 50 57 53 56 56 58
45 49 49 50 59 54 51 58 55 56 57 60
47 52 51 50 62 55 53 59 56 56 57 60
50 53 53 51 62 56 55 60 60 56 64 60
50 54 55 51 62 57 56 62 60 58 68 62
53 54 56 52 63 58 56 65 60 60 68 63
56 59 59 54 65 59 57 65 63 60 73 63
"), header = FALSE)

# t-values can be inserted by repeating @acrun's solution
dat$t.1 <- mapply(function(x, y, z) ifelse(x=="m", m.1[y, z], f.1[y, z]),
                  dat$sex, dat$raw.score.1, dat$age)
dat$t.2 <- mapply(function(x, y, z) ifelse(x=="m", m.2[y, z], f.2[y, z]),
                  dat$sex, dat$raw.score.2, dat$age)

# the result looks as it should
dat
#   code sex age raw.score.1 raw.score.2 t.1 t.2
# 1  A01   f   6          12           6  52  50
# 2  B02   m   8           5           3  45  43

# let's delete the columns with the t-values
dat$t.1 <- NULL
dat$t.2 <- NULL

# and try to define a function outsife of mapply()
t.fun <- function(v, w, x, y, z) ifelse(x=="m", v[y, z], w[y, z])

# but mapply() reduces the t-value tables to one row, too
dat$t.1 <- mapply(t.fun,
                  m.1, f.1, dat$sex, dat$raw.score.1, dat$age)
# Error in w[y, z] : incorrect number of dimensions

dat$t.2 <- mapply(t.fun,
                  m.2, f.2, dat$sex, dat$raw.score.2, dat$age)
# Error in w[y, z] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: The subset of `m` and `f` are `data.frame` with more than one column.  So, I am not sure how you are assigning it to a single 't.value' column

Comment: @akrun I was expecting the `dat$raw.score` in `m[dat$raw.score, dat$age]` to contain only a single value for each loop over the rows of dat, just as the `dat$sex` in `dat$sex == "m"` contains only a single value and not the whole column. See the example given under "what I expected". It is not clear to me why the five `dat$...` are handled differently within the `ifelse()`-statement.

Comment: It won't work because the `Map/mapply` compares the corresponding elements here.  For `m.1` and `f.1` it is the columns, and for `dat$sex`, `dat$raw.score.1`, `data$age`, it is the element itself as it is a vector.  So we are comparing 12 columns with 2 elements.  Instead it should be `mapply(t.fun, list(m.1), list(f.1), dat$sex, dat$raw.score.1, dat$age)` as `m.1` and `f.1` are both required as a whole dataset for each of the elements of `dat$sex` etc.

Comment: Thank you, @akrun, for your great help. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mapply/Map`

```
dat$t.value <- mapply(function(x, y, z) ifelse(x=="m", m[y, z], f[y, z]), 
              dat$sex, dat$raw.score, dat$age)
dat$t.value
#[1] 52 45
```

---

But, this can be vectorized by creating an index ('i1') and then assigning the values bassed on the logical index

```
i1 <- dat$sex=="m"
dat$t.value[i1] <- m[dat$raw.score[i1], dat$age[i1]]
dat$t.value[!i1] <- f[dat$raw.score[!i1], dat$age[!i1]]
dat 
#  code sex age raw.score t.value
#1  A01   f   6        12      52
#2  B02   m   8         5      45
```

Comment: Do you know if it is somehow possible to refer to the male/female tables by reference inside `mapply()`? When I try `mapply(function(u, v, x, y, z) ifelse(x=="m", u[y, z], v[y, z]), table.m, table.f, dat$sex, dat$raw.score, dat$age)` the dimensions of the tables get reduced to one row, too, and I get the error "incorrect number of dimensions".

Comment: @what What are `table.m` and `table.m` objects?  Are they matrix or table or data.frame class?

Comment: They are data.frames. See `m <- ...` and `f <- ...` in my question. (I wrote "table.m" in my comment instead of just "m" to make it clear that these where outside of and separate from "dat".

Comment: @what Could you please update your post with a small example that show the error

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through by row using something like `sapply`...

```
dat$t.value <- sapply(1:nrow(dat),function(i) ifelse(dat$sex[i] == "m",
                                           m[dat$raw.score[i], dat$age[i]],
                                           f[dat$raw.score[i], dat$age[i]]))

dat
  code sex age raw.score  t
1  A01   f   6        12 52
2  B02   m   8         5 45
```